# How to return Highcharts in Apollo Query component?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, apollo

I am trying to return graphql data in a Highchart. Somehow it is not being displayed. See live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qqv4pqn6w6).

```
import React from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";

import { ExchangeRates, client } from "./query";

class OtherComponentTest extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    <Query query={ExchangeRates} client={client}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (error) return <h1>Error...</h1>;
        if (loading || !data) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

        return Highcharts.chart("production", {
          ...
        });
      }}
    </Query>;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="production">loading </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OtherComponentTest;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just add JSX to your componentDidMount method like that and expect it to do something. Your code will just be transpiled into a call to `React.createElement` but the element itself will never be rendered. There's a couple of different ways you could this:

One, create a wrapper component for your highcharts container.

```
// elsewhere...
class HighchartsComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    Highcharts.chart("production", {
      series: this.props.series,
      // other config
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <div id="production">loading</div>
  }
}

// inside whatever render method
<Query query={ExchangeRates} client={client}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => {
    if (error) return <h1>Error...</h1>;
    if (loading || !data) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

    return <HighchartsComponent series={data.someQuery.someField}/>
  }}
</Query>
```

Two, utilize either the [ApolloConsumer](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#apollo-consumer) component or the [withApollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#withApollo) HOC
to directly access your Apollo client instance. Inside `componentDidMount`, you can then call the `query` method directly and use the results. Something like:

```
const { data } = await this.props.client.query({ query: ExchangeRates })
if (data && data.someQuery) {
  Highcharts.chart("production", {
    series: data.someQuery.someField,
    // other config
  })
}
```

Three, use the [official library](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) for React from the Highcharts team.

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

<Query query={ExchangeRates} client={client}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => {
    if (error) return <h1>Error...</h1>;
    if (loading || !data) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

    return (
      <HighchartsReact
        // your props here
      />
    )
  }}
</Query>
```

Comment: Okay, I see. What is the issue in my live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qqv4pqn6w6)? And how can I define the data in the options constant?

Comment: @Peterhack Your question does not include a link to a demo.

Comment: Yeah, something's borked with CodeSandbox I expect. It can't seem to find the `highcharts-react-official` even though you added it to your dependencies. There's other examples out there using the same library that seem to work fine (https://codesandbox.io/s/50p5l109nn)

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7wn9m7oy26). Regarding highcharts react, you just have to remove it in the codesandbox and add it again, then it works. Only thing I do not know how to solve is how to refer to the querried `data.rates` for the data field under `const options`?

Comment: You can move `options` within the `Query` component's render function. Then it will be in the same scope as data

Comment: Yes I know, but how can I achieve a seperation like I tried in the demo?

Comment: You could always use `Object.assign` to merge two objects together